# Dropdown within mobile navigation menu on stackoverflow.co doesn't open

Tags: bug, responsive-design, navigation, stackoverflow.co

On Stack Overflow's marketing website [stackoverflow.co](https://stackoverflow.co), nothing happens when I click on the dropdown in mobile responsive view. The same goes for every page on that website, such as [/teams](https://stackoverflow.co/teams/).

> [image]

With this issue, there's no way to navigate through the website on a mobile device.

It was reproduced on both desktop (in responsive design mode) and mobile Safari, latest version for both.